# Azure .NET SDK Documentation Missing

Tags: .net, azure

Azure REST APIs are well documented but I cannot find decent documentation for the Azure .NET SDK. Just as an example, I tried to delete and create a managed SQL database using the SDK. There is no documentation explaining the use of `SqlManagementClient` or even any info that I should be using `SqlManagementClient` for this purpose. I just found some samples here and there as a result of Google search.

Is it really that the .NET SDK for Azure is not properly documented or am I missing where it is? I would appreciate it if anyone could share a link to such documentation. (and I don't mean the API references.)

Comment: When you say "there is no documentation explaining the use of" - do you mean there is no example and sample documentation (because there definitely is [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.sqlmanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet), but that's not the same thing)

Comment: I found this (old: from 2015) archive copy of Microsoft's old Azure documentation with an example involving `SqlManagementClient`, see https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-csharp.md - but it's been removed from MS's documentation site for good reasons: the libraries mentioned have been obsoleted years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, John, for raising this up, the reason is that for .net SDK we are in the process of upgrading to a new version which follows a new [design principle](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/general_introduction.html), with the new design, it would be easy for us to create sample codes or documents. For your specific question, I'd suggest you can check [Azure Resource Management with Azure .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/resource-management), all SDK usage of managing azure resource follows the same principle.

Thanks again for letting us know your concerns about Azure SDK and we value all customer voices against Azure SDK.